# How do I avoid a server-client-server round-trip while moving files on a NAS?

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management, nas

I have stored all my data in my home network on a NAS server. Sometimes I need to move (rearrange) large files and directories from one place to another within the NAS. Using Windows Explorer, WinSCP or similar always results in the file being copied locally over the network to the computer, which I'm working on and then back to the destination directory, instead of moved directly within the server. This can take a considerable amount of time.

What I'm looking for is some a graphical file manager (in style of WinSCP, Windows Explorer, Total Commander or similar), which is smart enough to recognize that the source and destination directory are on the same server and move the file/directory wihin the server without an unnecessary roundtrip to the local computer. Is there such a program? I can of course login with SSH and use the mv command - however I would prefer a GUI solution.

Comment: Tehnically, what you are asking is impossible.  The protocols that file managers use to access network shares does not allow programs to issue "local" calls.  This is why you need to switch protocols, like SSH, VNC, etc, which will allow local call.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Samba on that NAS. Exactly how do you access your files with Explorer?
When you use Explorer or any other usual file manager to connect to `\\your-nas-ip-or-name\share\` Samba does the right thing.

Comment: The server is a QNAP TS-239 Pro, and I use Samba. I connect either by mounted network drives, e.g. drive P is assigned to path \\nas\photos\

Comment: I did a quick test again, and this time it seemed to work as you said. I'll do some more tests to see if I can establish a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Does your NAS have multiple volumes?

If so, a cut and paste on the same volume can be done as a quick rename/mv. A move across volumes would require a full copy.